# Carrierware: store file in directories accordint to created_at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to handle my uploads. I have specified the **store_dir** following way:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{Time.now.year}/#{Time.now.month}/#{Time.now.day}"
end
```

Uploading files work like a charm - each time I upload a file it ends up in directory where it should end; i.e. "today's directory".

When I try to download the file, carrierwave is constructing the download path dynamically based on **store_dir** options. So lets say a file which was uploaded on 1.12.2012 is available on the following path on fliesystem:

```
/uploads/2012/12/01/file.ext
```

will be retrieved by carrierwave as:

```
/uploads/2012/12/12/file.ext
```

Which obviously leads to "Cannot read file" error.

I came with 2 different possible solutions:

1. Create a separate filed where I will be storing the actual filepath to the file upon it's creation and then will use this value to retrieve file.
2. Overload **retrieve_from_store!** method (which is part of carrierwave gem) and make it construct path based on **created_at** field from the file record than rather from **store_dir**.

I am inclining to the second possibility since it feels not that dirty. Yet both feel "not-rails-way". Which one will be better to use and why? Or maybe carrierwave provides a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally guessing here but by looking at the docs I think something like this should work:

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.created_at.year}/#{model.created_at.month}/#{model.created_at.day}"
end
```